# Shipment section in admin pannel is not shown

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, importexport, shipment

[image: no tabs]

In admin panel under sales > order  while trying to create shipment , no tabs under the `Items to Ship` is shown.

After enabling and disabling every module one by one i found that one of custom module is the reason for this.

`I am using this custom module to have a custom importer/exporter which is working fine.`

So when that custom module is disabled this section is hidden, and when that module is enabled this section is shown.

Can any one suggest which part of a module can do this.

NOTE:Can i post the complete custom module here for reference.or any specific part.